# Mongodb/Mongo Query: How do I deserialize nested JSON stored in a string field?

Tags: json, mongodb, metabase

In the context of metabase:

I am applying the following one-liner query to extract a particular field from a collection of mongodb documents:

```
[{"$project":{"myName":"$field1.field2" }},
    {"$match":{"_id":{"$eq":"blah"}}}      ]
```

`myName` is a string field that is in fact a serialized JSON object.

How can I adapt the pipeline above, perhaps using `JSON.parse()`, to pull out fields nested further down the JSON hierarchy?

Part II: How would I add a final step to extract some of those deeply nested fields? The situation is further complicated because the document structure is not consistent between documents...

Thanks!

Comment: *"How can I adapt the pipeline above, perhaps using JSON.parse().."* - Aggregation pipelines do not run JavaScript functions. There are no aggregation operators to parse JSON in any way. The bigger question is just "why" would you store a "JSON string" in a field in MongoDB? Why did you not simply `JSON.parse()` **before** you stored it? Because if you did, then MongoDB can manipulate it just like any other document. But not as a "string". This really sounds more like a hangover from an RDBMS implementation that should have been converted earlier.

Comment: Also `$unwind` as the very first pipeline stage is very wasteful. You should almost always begin with `$match`.